# Minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{2} + \omega$ over $\mathbb{Q}.$

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Is the polynomial $f(x) = x^9 - 9x^6 - 27x^3 - 27$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}?$ I think it is because of Eisenstein's applied to the prime $3.$

Is it the minimal polynomial of $x = e^{2 \pi i/3} + \sqrt[3]{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? Wolfram Alpha says the answer is $x^6+3 x^5+6 x^4+3 x^3+9 x+9.$

I am a bit confused.

Comment: Eisestein's criterion does not apply here because $3^2=9$ divides $27$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that Eisenstein's criterion requires $p^2$ to **not** divide the constant term.  Your polynomial is reducible.  Note that the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ is the quadratic $x^2 + x + 1$, so the extension $\Bbb Q(\omega, \sqrt[3]{2})$ is of degree six, and thus $\omega + \sqrt[3]{2}$ has a minimal polynomial of degree dividing six.

(Wolfram alpha factors $ x^9 - 9x^6 - 27x^3 - 27$ as $x^3-3x^2+3x-3$ times the degree six polynomial you cite in your question.)

Comment: When I made the substitution $x \mapsto y+1,$ I obtained $y^9+9 y^8+36 y^7+75 y^6+72 y^5-9 y^4-123 y^3-180 y^2-126 y-62,$ which satisfies Eisenstein's Criterion for $p=3.$ What does this imply about the original polynomial? Also, how can I obtain $x^3-3x^2+3x-3?$

Comment: note that 3 does not divide 62, so Eisenstein's criterion is again invalid.  To obtain $x^3-3x^2+3x-3$, the easiest way I can think of is polynomial long division by the minimal polynomial $x^6+3x^5+6x^4+6x^3+9x+9$.  If you want to see why this is the minimal polynomial, you can either use brute-force linear algebra in $\Bbb Q(\omega, \sqrt[3]{2})$ or you can compute the polynomial $(x-\alpha_1)\cdots (x-\alpha_6)$, where the $\alpha_i$ are the conjugates of $\omega + \sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, can you clarify what you mean by conjugates? What will the $\alpha_i$ be? I'm unable to complete the computations.

Comment: The conjugates are the other five elements that are roots of $\omega + \sqrt[3]{2}$'s minimal polynomial (i.e., they consist of its image under the Galois action).  Note that there are automorphisms of $\mathbb Q(\omega, \sqrt[3]{2})$ fixing $\omega$ sending $\sqrt[3]{2}$ to the other two roots of $x^3- 2$, namely $\omega \sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\omega^2 \sqrt[3]{2}$.  Similarly, there is an automorphism fixing $\sqrt[3]{2}$ and sending $\omega$ to $\omega^2$.  This tells us that the conjugates are of the form $\omega^i + \omega^j\sqrt[3]{2}$ where $1\le i \le 2, 0 \le j \le 2$.

Comment: 1. Is there a direct way to see that $\sqrt[3]{2} + \omega$ has degree $6$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ (without computing the minimal polynomial, for instance)? $\tag*{}$ 2. What would be the easiest way of computing the minimal polynomial, according to you? Computing $(x-a_1) \cdots (x-a_6)$ seems very long. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Watson since $\omega$ has degree 2 and $\sqrt[3]{2}$ has degree 3 over $\Bbb Q$, we have that $\Bbb Q(\omega,\sqrt[3]{2})$ is a degree 6 field extension.  To see this degree is equal to the degree of $\omega + \sqrt[3]{2}$, you need to check that it generates all of $\Bbb Q(\omega, \sqrt[3]{2}$, which almost as involved as computing the minimal polynomial directly.  For the second question, I'm not sure there is a way much faster than expanding by hand, maybe if you pick elements carefully then you can get $(x-a_4)(x-a_5)(x-a_6)$ from applying a Galois automorphism to $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)$.